# Struts 2 plugin Conversion - from Codebehind to Convention plugin

Tags: java, struts2, annotations, struts-config, struts2-convention-plugin

I'm getting confusion to converting the *codebehind* annotation to conventional `struts.xml` file.

How to identify action name in action class? Because if write method `public String list{}` - action its match with JSPs `product-list.jsp` will automatically identify the page and URL was `product!list` like that. What is going to be conventional plugin ?

**current URL :**

`http://localhost:7001/example/product!search`- jsp name `product-search.jsp` and `ProductAction` - action class.

Please tell me how to configure the `struts.xml` file which equivalent above config.

**I have tried like below:**

```
<package name="example" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="Search">
    <result>product-search.jsp</result>
  </action>         
</package>
```

**Error :**

```
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher - Could not find action or result
There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name part. - [unknown location]
```

Comment: Please let me know if you not understand the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Struts2 actions are mapped on methods. The above url you should map as

```
<package name="example" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
   <action name="product" method="search"> <!-- case sensitive -->
     <result>product-search.jsp</result>
   </action>
</package>
```

or via annotations

```
@Namespace("/")
public class ProductAction extends ActionSupport {

  public String execute() {
    return SUCCESS;

  }

  @Action(value="product",
    results=@Result(location="/product-list.jsp")
  )
  public String search() {
    return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

Notice, that the method `execute` is not mapped, so it will not execute. If you need that method execute you should create mapping to it. For this purpose you could place annotation on class or on method `execute`.

More examples you could find on the page  [Convention Plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/convention/).