# Struts 2 post back default

Tags: annotations, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin

In the Struts documentation, it says:

[Post back default](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-configuration.html#post-back-default)

> Another common workflow stategy is to first render a page using an alternate method, like input and then have it submit back to the default execute method.

How to do it using annotation only? It seems that only the `execute()` method is called.

Comment: What annotation did you mean?

Comment: Struts 2 annotations.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation it's said to render a page can be used  an alternate method like `input`. This means that when you submit a form on the page it can return back with the `input` result. Usually it happens automatically during validation process if the validation fails or it `hasErrors`. Then you can submit the form back to the default action's `execute` method. You don't need to specify a `method` in the action configuration. Also if you didn't specify the `action` attribute in the `form` tag then the same action will execute which was used to render a page.

Configuring actions you can use the same page for `success` result when rendering a page using `GET` method and  `input` when `POST` method is requested.

To use annotations to configure actions mapping you can use a [Convention Plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/convention/).

Also note, to map a class method to the action you should put `@Action` annotation directly on this method rather than on the class.

More detailed explanation and documentation you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17388896/573032).

> ```
> @Namespace("/")
> public class ProductAction extends ActionSupport  {
>
>  public String execute() { 
>    return SUCCESS;
>
>  }
>
>  @Action(value="product",
>    results=@Result(location="/product-list.jsp")
>  )
>  public String search() {
>    return SUCCESS;
>  }
> }
> ```
>
> Notice, that the method `execute` is not mapped, so it will not execute. If you need that method execute you should create mapping to it. For this purpose you could place annotation on class or on method `execute`.